# Set hostname for local docker-desktop, kubernetes, helm deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following question regarding deployments using HELM, Kubernetes and docker-desktop:

I defined a load-balancer using kubernetes and helm as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "api.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "api.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
```

I can start all pods and the service. However, the external IP of my loadbalancer service is "localhost".

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP
api      LoadBalancer   10.103.231.18   localhost
```

How do I configure helm/kubernetes to assign a domain name to my service like described in the [kubernetes docu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). Something like myservice.default.svc.cluster.local?

I would appreciate any pointers, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything.  Every Service, regardless of the type, gets the `service-name.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local` in-cluster DNS name.  That won't show up as the "external IP" value, but conversely, that DNS name also isn't resolvable from outside the cluster.

In your output the Service is named `api`, so the in-cluster DNS name will be something like `api.default.svc.cluster.local`, and short names `api.default` and (for Pods in the `default` namespace) `api` will work as well.